# Как отключить перестройку динамически построенной таблицы в ASP.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

```
protected void build_table()
{
    ...
    foreach (DataRow row in Stages.Rows)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numrows; j++)
        {
            if (MySQL.myData.Length == j) break;
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < numcells; k++)
            {
                if (row_id != Convert.ToInt16(row["ID"]))
                {
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
                        thc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(row["ID"].ToString()));
                        tr.Cells.Add(thc);
                    }
                    else if (k == 1)
                    {
                        TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
                        thc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(row["Name"].ToString()));
                        tr.Cells.Add(thc);
                        thc.ColumnSpan = 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row_id = Convert.ToInt16(row["ID"]);
                        MySQL.Connect("SELECT position, ppe.name FROM pp_existing_stages pes LEFT JOIN pp_events ppe ON pes.id_event = ppe.id WHERE id_plan = (SELECT id FROM pp_plan WHERE pp_information = '" + plan + "') AND id_stage = " + row_id + " ORDER BY position");
                        j--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                        tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(row_id + "." + MySQL.myData[j].ItemArray[k].ToString()));
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    }
                    else if (k == 1)
                    {
                        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                        tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(MySQL.myData[j].ItemArray[k].ToString()));
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    }
                    else if (k == 2)
                    {
                        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                        txt.ID = "price_" + row_id + "_" + MySQL.myData[j].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                        txt.Attributes.Add("style", "width:100%");
                        tc.Controls.Add(txt);
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    }
                    else if (k == 3)
                    {
                        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                        txt.ID = "week_" + row_id + "_" + MySQL.myData[j].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                        txt.Attributes.Add("style", "width:100%");
                        tc.Controls.Add(txt);
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    }
                }
            }
            Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Вызов функции

```
protected void Selection_Change1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ............
    if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
        build_table();
}
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ........            
    var pp_index = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["pp_index"]);
    if (!IsPostBack)
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pp_index))
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(pp_index);
            Selection_Change1(DropDownList1, System.EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    ........
}
```

Формируется таблица вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У каждого поля ввода в таблице уникальный id (`price_1_1`, `price_2_3` и т.д.)

Пользователь должен заполнять поля. Внизу таблицы есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую данные должны отправляться на серверную часть и там обрабатываться.

Проблема в том, что нажатие кнопки вызывает перезагрузку страницы, что впоследствии приводит к очистке введённых данных.

Можно ли решить проблему  без использования jQuery? Если да, то как? Если нет, то как подобное можно реализовать на jQuery (пример был бы очень кстати).

Наверняка есть возможность забирать все введённые данные в момент нажатия на кнопку, но, до перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: А как предполагается на серверной стороне доставать данные, введенные в `TextBox`-ы?

Comment: @Igor `TextBox price_txt = (TextBox)Table1.FindControl("price_" + (i + 1) + "_" + (j + 1));` без проблем находит в цикле все TextBox-ы. Если бы они не удалялись при перезагрузке, проблем бы не было.

Comment: Вам надо вызывать код заполнения таблицы каждый раз при загрузке страницы в `Page_Load`.

Comment: @Igor Таблица то и заполняется после каждой перезагрузки. Проблема в том, что я из `TextBox'ов` введённую пользователем информацию не могу вытащить до того, как она удалится. Нажатие на кнопку под таблицей вызывает сперва `Page_Load` (который перестраивает таблицу и, из-за этого удаляет всю информацию из `TextBox'ов`), а только после этого `Button1_Click(...)`, который должен забирать информацию из `TextBox'ов`.

Comment: "из-за этого удаляет всю информацию из TextBox'ов" - Всё не так. Заполнение таблицы в `Page_Load` и нужно как раз для того, чтобы `TextBox`-ы получили свои значения из запроса. Добавляйте больше кода в вопрос.

Comment: Отлично. А теперь, пожалуйста, добавьте код всех мест, где вызывается `build_table()`.

Comment: @Igor сделал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот. У Вас заполнение таблицы происходит только в случае GET запроса:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
```

а должно - всегда. `TextBox`-ы сами ниоткуда не появятся.

Comment: Я и не знал, что это так работает. Спасибо огромное. Выручили прям